# python spacy looking for two (or more) words in a window

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, matcher

I am trying to identify concepts in texts. Oftentimes I consider that a concept appears in a text when two or more words appear relatively close to each other.
For instance a concept would be any of the words
*forest*, *tree*, *nature*
in a distance less than 4 words from
*fire*, *burn*, *overheat*

I am learning spacy and so far I can use the matcher like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("HelloWorld", None, [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"LOWER": "world"}],[{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}])
```

That would match *hello world* and *hello, world* (or *tree firing* for the above mentioned example)

I am looking for a solution that would yield matches of the words *Hello* and *World* within a window of 5 words.

I had a look into:
https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching

and the operators there described, but I am not able to put this word-window approach in "spacy" syntax.

Furthermore, I am not able to generalize that to more words as well.

Some ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a window with K words, where K is relatively small, you can add K-2 optional wildcard tokens between your words. *Wildcard* means "any symbol", and in Spacy terms it is just an empty dict. *Optional* means the token may be there or may not, and in Spacy in is encoded as `{"OP": "?"}`.

Thus, you can write your matcher as

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("HelloWorld", None, [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"OP": "?"},  {"OP": "?"}, {"OP": "?"}, {"LOWER": "world"}])
```

which means you look for "hello", then 0 to 3 tokens of any kind, then "world". For example, for

```
doc = nlp(u"Hello brave new world")
for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

it will print you

```
15578876784678163569 HelloWorld 0 4 Hello brave new world
```

And if you want to match the other order (world ? ? ? hello) as well, you need to add the second, symmetric pattern into your matcher.

Answer (score 2):

I'm relatively new to spaCy but I think the following pattern should work for any number of tokens between 'hello' and 'world' that are comprised of ASCII characters:

```
[{"LOWER": "hello"}, {'IS_ASCII': True, 'OP': '*'}, {"LOWER": "world"}]
```

I tested it using Explosion's [rule-based match explorer](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=A%20match%20is%20a%20tool%20for%20starting%20a%20fire.%20Typically%2C%20modern%20matches%20are%20made%20of%20small%20wooden%20sticks%20or%20stiff%20paper.%20One%20end%20is%20coated%20with%20a%20material%20that%20can%20be%20ignited%20by%20frictional%20heat%20generated%20by%20striking%20the%20match%20against%20a%20suitable%20surface.%20Wooden%20matches%20are%20packaged%20in%20matchboxes%2C%20and%20paper%20matches%20are%20partially%20cut%20into%20rows%20and%20stapled%20into%20matchbooks.&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22ADJ%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%3F%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LEMMA%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22match%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22POS%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22NOUN%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LEMMA%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22be%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22IS_ASCII%22%2C%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22*%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A5%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LEMMA%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22a%22%7D%5D%7D%5D) and it works.  Overlapping matches will return just one match (eg, "hello and I do mean hello world').